# Spark Stops indefinitely and does not process anything on when trying to connect to adls gen2 azure using java

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-data-lake

I am trying to connect to Adls gen2 storage on azure using spark and java .
Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Adls connection");
        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).master("local[*]").getOrCreate();

        sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.adl.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem");
        sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth");
        sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider");
        sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<client-id>");
        sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<client-secret>");
        sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token");
        String path = "adl://<account-name>.azuredatalakestore.net/data/*.csv";
        
        sparkSession.read().format("csv").option("header",true).load(path);

    }

'''

But on running this spark after giving few log message gets stuck and nothing happens. 
Could you please help me what i am doing wrong
```

Comment: Can you try giving path as `abfss://data@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file>` and try? (Considering the container name is data in your case)

Comment: After the changes  it's giving error as: Exception in thread main Unable to load key provider class